# Passing value into next Promises argument

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

Basically, i'm so confused with the Promises. Because, I'm still new to moved on from Callback method for handling Asynchronous.

So, i have a code like these

```js
const Search = function(name) { //
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { //
    let o = [{
        "name": "Apple",
        "quantity": 10
      },
      {
        "name": "Grape",
        "quantity": 5
      }
    ]
    let result = o.filter((n) => n.name == name)
    if (result.length < 1) {
      reject()
      return
    }
    resolve(result[0])
  })
}

const Buy = function(data, qty) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let o = {
      name,
      quantity
    } = data
    o.quantity = parseInt(o.quantity) - qty
    if (o.quantity < 0) {
      throw new Error("Oops. Quantity is Empty!")
    }
    resolve(o)
  })
}

const Result = function(test) {
  console.log(test)
}
```

The main purpose, how i can input a value into a `qty` arguments on Buy function?

I was do something like this, but the result is not expected what i want. I'm sure, my code has something missing but i don't know.

```js
Search("Apple")
  .then(Buy, 4)
  .then(Result)
```

The result is :

```
{ name: 'Apple', quantity: NaN }
```

Main goal is :

```
{ name: 'Apple', quantity: 6 }
```

Anyway thanks :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass parameter to a promise function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35318442/how-to-pass-parameter-to-a-promise-function)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Search("Apple")
  .then(function(result){return Buy(result, 4)})
  .then(Result)
```

You were trying to pass `Buy` directly into `.then`, but the function in `.then` always gets passed only 1 argument. So you can call and return `Buy` in an anonymous function, where you can apply yourself as many arguments you want.

Comment: Ahh, I see. So, then itself has 1 argument only so we need modifying then function and returning manually into another function?

Comment: Yes. [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#Parameters) talks about the 'onFulfilled' parameter, "A Function called if the Promise is fulfilled. This function has one argument, the fulfillment value.", which is the value that is resolved from the promise.

Answer (score 3):

You can take advantage of scope.

```
function executeSearch() {
    Search("Apple").then(function (searchResult) {

        // feel free to use the result of the first promise 
        // as input parameters to the second if desired
        const name = searchResult.name;
        const quantity = searchResult.quantity;

        Buy(searchResult, 4).then(Result);

    });
}
```

This is similar to the other answer but demonstrates that you can use the result of the first promise in any number of ways to execute the second promise.

Comment: Whats `const { name, quantity } = searchResult;` for?

Comment: @Satpal it's simply a demonstration to show that you have access to those variables in that context, and you can use them as input parameters if desired.

Answer (score 2):

The `then` method accepts a function, so what you can do is change your 'buy' to the following:

```
const Buy = function(qty) {
  return function(data){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let o = {
        name,
        quantity
      } = data
      o.quantity = parseInt(o.quantity) - qty
      if (o.quantity < 0) {
        throw new Error("Oops. Quantity is Empty!")
      }
      resolve(o)
    })
  }
}
```

Then you can use it like:

```
Search("Apple")
  .then(Buy(4))
  .then(Result)
```

Comment: I actually thought of this solution as well -- returning a function, almost like a 'curried' function situation. The only downside is that the logic is, to me, a bit harder to follow when you have functions returning functions like this.